# Remove malformed iOS app from device

Tags: itunes, ios

I incorrectly edited the plist that goes with an .ipa file and tried to install this .ipa.
Thereafter the app shows with a missing icon:

[image]

So now I'm not able to delete application that incorrectly installed.

- Long press on app, selecting **✕** and Delete option does nothing.
- Have tried to do it through iTunes with no result.
- Rebooting doesn't help.

I can remove all other applications on device.

**UPDATE 1:**
After fixing plist, installation goes with success, but old application remains:
[image: App on home screen]

<sup>I'm using iPad mini with iOS 7.0.3.

I know how to correctly install my app, my question is about how to remove aftermath of my last try.</sup>

Comment: Have you tried fixing the plist and installing the app again?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the device?

Comment: @MarkThalman, yes, see screenshot in my post

Comment: @Undo, yes, have tried reboot many times

Answer (score 1):

Go into Settings > General > Usage

From there find and tap on the app in the list of installed apps and select delete app.

Comment: This list do not contain my app. Maybe it's because application installed incorrectly or installed not completely.

Comment: Try signing out of the App Store on the device. I'm not sure if that will help in this case but its worth a shot.

Comment: Sign out do not help.